# Haskell IORef array usage

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, monads, ioref

I am working on an program that uses a large list of `IORef`'s to a data type. Which is the more memory/processor-efficient way to do this:

```
[IORef Foo]
```

or

```
IORef [Foo]
```

Ignore the fact that I am using lists instead of vectors or arrays.

Comment: On the other hand, [IORef] lets you change the number of items, while IORef [] doesn't. Therefore, a suggestion: use IORef [IORef].

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `IOArray` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `[IORef Foo]` you can update elements easily, with `IORef [Foo]`, you can only update the whole list. Since you're likely wanting to efficiently update elements without copying, you want `[IORef Foo]`. Think, you want a list of mutable things, not a mutable list of immutable things.

As an example

```
import Data.IORef

makeTest :: IO [IORef Int]
makeTest = sequence [newIORef 0, newIORef 1, newIORef 2]

main = do
  test <- makeTest
  readIORef (test !! 1) >>= print
  modifyIORef (test !! 1) (+1) -- Doesn't copy list
  readIORef (test !! 1) >>= print
```